# How to return emr cluster id in output section of cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, output, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

As mentioned in the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticmapreduce-cluster.html) I see that there is a way to expose the EMR cluster ID

> *Return Values*:
>   **Ref**
>   When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic *Ref* function, 
>   *Ref* returns returns the cluster ID, such as j-1ABCD123AB1A.

Can I please have an example how do I put this in *output* section of the cloudformation template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming JSON:

```
"Outputs" : {
  "ClusterID" : {
    "Description" : "the EMR cluster ID",
    "Value" : { "Ref" : "myCluster" }
  }
}
```

where `myCluster` is the logical ID of the EMR  cluster resource in your template.